# If CORS if refusing my API request and I don't control the server, is there nothing I can do?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, cors, xmlhttprequest

*So as I understand it*, the person who hosts content on their server can set CORS headers which specify who can access this content and what they can do with it. The owner can also prevent certain sites from accessing these items by only allowing specific sites through using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

**Is any of that correct, or have I misunderstood how CORS works?**

I am trying to access information from a server I do not control and am receiving the CORS error below. I **am** using the API provided by the owners, but I'm making requests from my localhost dev server and wonder if this might be causing issues? I am developing using Quasar and Vue and I'm very, very new to developing generally - please excuse any obvious mistakes/oversights.

Here's my code:

```
var data = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});

xhr.open('GET', 'url');
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Correlation-Id', 'id');
xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'something+json; UTF-8');
xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', 'Basic username:password');

xhr.send(data);
```

And I'm receiving this:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I have almost no idea what this means, and I have done a fair bit of reading trying to understand it. If there is an obvious fix, please go the step further to explain it to me - thankyou!

Comment: use your own server to "proxy" your request - but it seems the server you are trying to access wants to allow CORS, just doesn't do it right when you set withCredentials true - are you sure you need withCredentials true?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a CORS proxy like [cors-anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) or you could even [make your own](https://github.com/ccoenraets/cors-proxy).